Manga where the female lead time travels back to her high school days, tries to save a boy from a fire
I'm searching for a manga where the a woman travels back in time when she visits her old high school.
During her high school days there was a guy (the male lead) who loves her so much and how they were so in love throughout their high school but a tragedy happened and he dies.
Years passed but she was never able to get over it, so when she time travels she tries to make the most out of it and decides to save him from the tragedy.
From what I recollect, whenever she tries to reach out to a particular guy (not the male lead) while time travelling she always comes back to reality and was never able to find out that person's face or something like that.
At almost the end of the manga, that guy (not the male lead) meets with her (in the present time) and tells her how he is time travelling and trying to change his own future but she is always messing it up whenever she tries to encounter her in the past (time travel past) and that there is only a limited time on how much time travelling he can do and that he only has one last time travelling he can do and that he can't help her.
She, devastated, tells him her story about how she wants to save the male lead and asks him for his help. Even after so much pressure he was reluctant, but on the day of his last time travel, she waits for him at the school, and seeing her, he reluctantly decides to help her out.
The way the male lead died is that there was this equipment storage at the school and one time when she was getting bullied by some girls and guys, they shut her in that room and unfortunately it seems one of the bullies mistakenly throws a cigar butt towards  the storage, or something like that, and the storage unit catches on fire. The male lead, while trying to help the female lead, dies in that fire.
At the end of the story it turns out that it was actually the female lead who died in the fire and the male lead was the one who keeps on time travelling to save her from that tragedy and every time he tries to save her, he dies in that fire so each time only one of them survives.
But it has a happy ending.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters?

Sounds similar to the one described at https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-anime-where-the-guy-goes-back-in-the-past-to-save-a-childhood-girl-1st-girl-which-he-succeeded-but-died-and-the-girlfriend-in-the-present-timeline-2nd-girl-couldnt-accept-and-went-to-the-past-to-prevent but the answers don't match.

I don't remember the characters name but I read it like last year , also it's coloured. And the story complete.

I found the name of the manga it's called"The Stairway of Time" after searching it for almost a week I finally found it

"Back to You"

What if an unexpected accident suddenly transported you back to ten years ago? For Hayoung, suddenly traveling back in time to high school means the opportunity to save the life of Jaehyun, the one person she's always loved... Will she be able to change both of their fates? - Back To You

A different synopsis.

Hayoung experiences an unexpected accident that sends her back in time to her high school days. She seizes this opportunity to save the life of Jaehyun, the person she has always loved. However, as she delves deeper into the past, she discovers that Jaehyun also has a connection to time travel. The manhwa explores their intertwined destines and the impact of their actions across time. - Copilot

Originally a webtoon series it was later turned into a short run graphic novel.

